# memoization question - My memo dict performs better than lru_cache. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memoization

I have been playing with memorization and `lru_cache`... I have a quick question as to why my memoization code runs better than `lru_cache`.

My code:

```py
memo = {}
def fib(n): 
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n < 2: 
        return 1
    else:
        if n not in memo:
            memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    return memo[n]
print(fib(900))
```

lru_cache code:

```py
from functools import lru_cache


@lru_cache(maxsize=1000)
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n < 2:
        return 1
    else:
       return fib(n -1) + fib(n -2)
    
    
print(fib(499))
```

The second I try to find the 500th fib number, I get the following error with lru_cache:

```
lk/Documents/VSCode/testing_zone/fibonacci_examples/fib_with_lru_cache.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\lk\Documents\VSCode\testing_zone\fibonacci_examples\fib_with_lru_cache.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(fib(500))
  File "c:\Users\lk\Documents\VSCode\testing_zone\fibonacci_examples\fib_with_lru_cache.py", line 11, in fib
    return fib(n -1) + fib(n -2)
  File "c:\Users\lk\Documents\VSCode\testing_zone\fibonacci_examples\fib_with_lru_cache.py", line 11, in fib
    return fib(n -1) + fib(n -2)
  File "c:\Users\lk\Documents\VSCode\testing_zone\fibonacci_examples\fib_with_lru_cache.py", line 11, in fib
    return fib(n -1) + fib(n -2)
  [Previous line repeated 496 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Yet on my simple dict memoization I can go up to 900 before I run into the same error

```
lk/Documents/VSCode/testing_zone/fibonacci_examples/fib_with_memo.py
54877108839480000051413673948383714443800519309123592724494953427039811201064341234954387521525390615504949092187441218246679104731442473022013980160407007017175697317900483275246652938800
```

My understanding is that both the dict and the `lru_cache` operate in the same way where they reference the dict or lru_cache to see if n is in them before recalling the `fib(n)` function.

My question is why are they not performing the same? Have I misconfigured the code or is there additional optimizations/code I need to use with `lru_cache`?

`lru_cache` must be working, as `fib(400)` is returned almost instantly, which wouldn't happen if the decorator was not there.

Comment: can you provide timing status ? why you conside one is better then another >

Comment: There may be a hint in the name `lru_cache` - yes it caches by using a dict, but it also records most recent usage and evicts least used entries once the cache is full. Compare with a functools.cache which doesn’t do the lru bit.

Comment: @sahasrara62, I don't consider one better than the other. My question is more around why can I calculate almost double the fib(n) 900 with the dict approach, vs only 499 with the lru_cache approach before I run into a RecursionError. 

Something must be going on under the hood, that I am unaware of, as my understanding is they operate the same.

Cheers, 
Liam

Comment: @balmy Nah, even with `@lru_cache(maxsize=3)` it works fine up to around n=500.

Comment: nice for a first question :)

Comment: The `@lru_cache` decorator replaces your function with a wrapper function that checks the cache, and then possibly calls the original function - so there are *two* function calls on the stack for every actual invocation of `fib()`.  Your version merges the cache check and the actual operation into a single function, so it consumes stack levels half as fast.

Comment: @jasonharper - Really helpful! As the decorator is a function in its own right; the call stack is doubled! That is an interesting consideration with decorators and something I would have never thought about! Thanks.

Comment: @Chris_Rands - Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your precise problem is that `@lru_cache` introduces a second function call. It literally puts a wrapper around the function `fib`.

When you think you're calling fib, you're actually calling the wrapper program.  It looks to see if the value is in its cache.  If so, it returns the value; if not, it calls the saved original definition of fib, puts the returned value in its cache, and then returns that value.

So when you call `fib(500)`, your function call depth is 1000.  Your memoization program has inlined its cache into the function body, so the call depth is only 500.   Hence the error about maximum recursion.

You can find out the current recursion limit using `sys.getrecursionlimit()`.  You can modify the limit using `sys.setrecursionlimit()`.

Comment: Really helpful explanation! - Thank you. Definitely something I would have never considered regarding the decorators call on the stack itself!

Comment: I will also add that I use `@lru_cache` (or `@cache` if I'm using ≥ 3.9) all the time.  The simplicity of adding a single line of code far outweighs any issues.  Writing one's own memoization and making sure every case is covered is tedious and error prone.